# How can I convert a wav file in java

Tags: java, audioformat

How can I convert a wav file in java

```
AudioFormat targetFormat = new AudioFormat(
                                    sourceFormat.getEncoding(),
                                    fTargetFrameRate,
                                    16,
                                    sourceFormat.getChannels(),
                                    sourceFormat.getFrameSize(),
                                    fTargetFrameRate,
                                    false);
```

in result Exception :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported conversion: 
ULAW 8000.0 Hz, **16 bit**, mono, 1 bytes/frame, **from** ULAW 8000.0 Hz, **8 bit**, mono, 1 bytes/frame
```

it is possible in java?

I need get wav file 16 bit, from 8

Comment: OK, so you want to convert from 8 to 16 bit?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a method that will convert an 8-bit uLaw encoded binary file into a 16-bit WAV file using built-in Java methods.

```
public static void convertULawFileToWav(String filename) {
    File file = new File(filename);
    if (!file.exists())
        return;
    try {
        long fileSize = file.length();
        int frameSize = 160;
        long numFrames = fileSize / frameSize;
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(Encoding.ULAW, 8000, 8, 1, frameSize, 50, true);
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(new FileInputStream(file), audioFormat, numFrames);
        AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, Type.WAVE, new File("C:\\file.wav"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is the full source: Convert a RTP sequence payload in a .wav file: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622397/convert-a-rtp-sequence-payload-in-a-wav-file/17732264#17732264](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11622397/convert-a-rtp-sequence-payload-in-a-wav-file/17732264#17732264)

Answer (score 1):

Look at this one: [Conversion of Audio Format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515174/conversion-of-audio-format-in-java) it is similar to your issue suggesting looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/AudioSystem.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always use FFMPEG, http://ffmpeg.org/, to do the conversion. Your Java program can call FFMPEG to do the conversion. 
 FFMPEG works on all OS.